# Why genymotion emulator is a lot faster than android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I've been using android emulator in Ubuntu 14.04, i5-2500k 3.2GHz, 8 GB RAM, but it was incredibly slow as I found genymotion emulator.

So, what's the difference between them? Why genymotion is so fast booting?

Thank you.

Comment: This is no longer the case. With HAXM and x86 android emulator are faster than genymotion. I've used both and android emulator is faster. You have to configure the emulator right to make it faster. For more details, check out my [blog about this](https://www.plightofbyte.com/android/2017/09/03/genymotion-vs-android-emulator).

Comment: Genymotion is much, much better if it comes to run multiple instances of emulator. Try to run 5x genymotion instances and do your test. Now, run the same instances od x86 emulator. With low end pc you will see only freezes.

When I run android emulator 1 instance takes 50-60% cpu usage, and 1200mb ram compared to 5-10% cpu usage and 100mb ram when using genymotion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably because Genymotion uses x86 instructions and is using your processor Vt-x features and rendering the graphics hw accelerated.
 It is a huge difference from the emulator that runs arm code under Windows.
Using VBox you can create a vm with the same setup and other version of Android x86. Do not forget to install the win drivers for your HW virtualization. Intel Core uses VT-x, but you have to install the module under the SDK Manager and then run setup from the file location.

MCP

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.genymotion.com:

> Genymotion is an emulator using x86 architecture virtualization, making it much more efficient!
>
> Taking advantage of OpenGL hardware acceleration, it allows you to test your applications with amazing 3D performance

On the other hand: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow)