# Android emulator doesn't starts

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created a simulator device Nexus with the following details, and cannot run this. This is always loading and not opened.

[image]

For this simulator, I just started it from AVD manager. It is showing only black screen with android text for long time.

Here is the SS.

[image]

What is my problem. I cant find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) set up correctly. You may have it installed, but sometimes it needs to be enabled in your bios. See [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) for information about setting it up.

Comment: @Ratwanska Hmm. Make sure you have all the necessary sdk installed for the version you're trying to emulate. To do this, go to the welcome window for studio (If you're in the IDE, go to file > close project), configure, then to sdk manager.) Also just make sure everything's up-to-date (Studio, HAXM, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use HAXM unless you have high speed processor such as core i7, because it takes too much time to compile and run the program. Instead use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) it won't take too much load.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exact problem, But Android simulator is not so fast.

I would recommend you for **[GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)**

Genymotion is the best Android Emulator for app testing and presentation. As a reference tool for Android developers.

The reason why I am recommending this.

[Why genymotion emulator is a lot faster than android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25424721/2022000)

Comment: Genymotion lacks Google Play Services, which a lot of apps may rely on.