# Android emulator issue with GPU driver

Tags: android, android-emulator, gpu, nvidia

I have a problem in my android emulator, every time I opened it ,this message appears and it is very very slow

[image]

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/45121828/6280796

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion - Use a different emulator ([Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)). It's faster than the inbuilt android emulator.[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424721/why-genymotion-emulator-is-a-lot-faster-than-android-emulator).