# HAX kernel module is not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just downloaded latest android studio from official android site and installed it. But I am getting this error instead of having Intel X 86 Emulator accelerator. What can cause this error

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reading many questions on stackoverflow I found out that my CPU does not support Virtualization. I have to upgrade to the cpu which supports Virtualization in order to install Intel X 86 Emulator accelerator(Haxm Installer)

Comment: Which processor you are using?

Comment: @achieverprince it's pretty old one, it does not support virtualization. Now bought the new PC , it supports the virtualization but not the intel virtualization (AMD).

Comment: got it, so even now you cant use Haxm since it is not intel.

Comment: @achieverprince Yup, i am using Genymotion for my android apps now. The android studio IDE should do something for AMD users

Comment: In my PC there is no virtualization. i can't install from sdk folder showing error "This Computer does not support Intel Virtuliazation TEchnology (Vt-x)"

Comment: @Prasad That's what the this answer is saying. If there is no visualization and that to of intel than you can't install HAXM. You ought to buy some new CPU that supports this or use any other emulator like GenyMotion.

Answer (score 71):

If you are running a **modern Intel processor** make sure HAXM (Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager) is installed:

1. In Android SDK Manager, ensure the option is ticked (and then installed)
2. Run the HAXM installer via the path below:

   ```
   your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe
   or
   your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe
   ```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs) shows all the required steps which may help you to solve the problem.

For **AMD CPUs** (or older Intel CPUs without VT-x technology), you will not be able to install this and the best option is to emulate your apps using [Genymotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw).  See: *[Intel's HAXM equivalent for AMD on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)*

Comment: at last this video helped me. I wasted huge time by checking up hiper-v check box. No documentation says it should be unchecked. Thank you very much dude.

Comment: Note that if you can't find your AppData\Local\Android\sdk path in Windows, try running %AppData% to find it.

Comment: I edited your post to add some additional details about AMD processors. I hope that's OK.

Comment: You will want to disable Hyper-V if getting errors about this. The below can help https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Answer (score 60):

Actual error

[image]

follow bellow two simple steps to fix.

Step 1:-
update
"Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" Ref. bellow img
[image]

Step2:-

After installing the installer, you have to run it to install it on your system. Open the directory where your Android SDK is located. Go inside the extras\Intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager directory and you should see the intelhaxm-android.exe file.

[image]

If you got the error "This computer meets requirements for HAXM, but VT-x is not turned on..." during installation try to turn it on in your BIOS and check your antivirus software settings also. (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working) stackoverflow post).
Thats it! its working for me.

Comment: HAXM insatallation failed,"Failed to configure driver:unknown error. Failed to open driver." this sis the error i'm getting while installing intel haxm in my pc.

Comment: In my PC there is no virtualization. i can't install from sdk folder showing error "This Computer does not support Intel Virtuliazation TEchnology (Vt-x)"

Comment: After this, when starting emulator, I get message "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode...", but then also "...Permission denied" and no emulator is opened.

Answer (score 23):

Recently, I have faced this issue. And fixed it by changing CPU/ABI from Intel Atom (x86) to ARM(armeabi-v7a).

- Select the Virtual Device. Click on Edit
- Click on CPU/ABI option
- Change it to ARM(armeabi-v7a) from intel. Click OK

Job done.

Comment: I also done the same thing as Doremon suggested, and its working fine.

Comment: My laptop does not support vitalization but **this work with me**

Answer (score 20):

Try installing it again with the stand alone installer https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement
- assuming you have a CPU that supports Virtualization, have turned off antivirus and any hypervisor.

Comment: @codecats: this might be totally unrelated, but do you know of any VM that can provide Hardware Virtualization and Hyper-V? Apparently Virtual Box doesn't support that.

Comment: I suggest you enter this as a new question and I think you'll get multiple responses about the possibilities.

Comment: My CPU does not support virtualization, is there any opportunity to go round?

Comment: @Jurgen - what CPU do you have?  There's always genymotion for non HAXM capable systems

Comment: B970, its in a Hp 650. The bios has not the opition to turn on/off virtualization in my HP laptop

Comment: That's a pentium from '012 - it does NOT have VT capability so HAXM is NOT an option. You could try genymotion.

Answer (score 8):

Since most modern CPUs support virtualization natively, the reason you received such message can be because virtualization is turned off on your machine. For example, that was the case on my HP laptop - the factory setting for hardware virtualization was "Disabled". So, go to your machine's BIOS and enable virtualization.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a solution for users with AMD CPUs.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to turn on virtualization on your machine. To do that, restart your machine. Press F2. Goto BIOS. Make Virtualization Enabled. Press F10. Start windows. Now, goto Extras folder of Android installation folder and find intel-haxm-android.exe. Run it. Start Android Studio. Now, it should allow you to run your program using emulator.

Comment: I have not visualization support in my PC. :-( +1 for your answer. My laptop had it enabled so working on it now

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a solution for users with AMD CPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Turning off HyperV on windows 8.1 did the trick for me

dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Comment: Thanks, that helped on my machine: W10 64Bit (Upgrade from 8.1), Intel i7-4770T

Comment: this worked only after running the command in a command prompt ran as administrator (right click on command prompt and select it)

Comment: you need also to restart the computer