# Android Emulator problems, CPU might not support virtualization?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to get back into android programming on my new computer.

I installed everything using TheNewBoston's tutorials 1-4 on YouTube, but when I go in to my AVD manager to run the Nexus 5 API 21 x86 I get the following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

So naturally I googled around and found several threads with the same problem and solutions.

[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Is one example and I also tried to manually install the "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) where I got the following problem.

```
Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver
```

So then I found this thread saying that my CPU might not support Virtualization, but I have no idea how to check if it is.

[HAX kernel module is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720064/hax-kernel-module-is-not-installed)

My CPU is an **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @3.40 GHz**. If it doesn't support Virtualization...what are my options? Can I still test my applications on a phone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question got nothing with java, android studio nor android activity. use proper tags. it's all about emulator

Comment: You can check here:http://ark.intel.com/

For yours specifically: http://ark.intel.com/products/65520/Intel-Core-i5-3570K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz

It shows that it is Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) capable.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry, I just thought it had to do with java since it was the language involved in android studio, and it was where I encountered the issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry your CPU does support virtualization. Please go to boot menu and enable your virtualization settings from there.
you'll be good to go then.