# CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed! Error Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I am facing an inexplicable error .Virtualization is turned on .I have install haxm successfully .Still when I try to run an application the following error is shown .I have added screenshot of Appearance and beahviour ->System settings-> Android SDK---SDK tools tab

```
 C:\Users\SACHIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
    emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
    Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
    CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

[image]

Comment: There are some solutions for your questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720064/hax-kernel-module-is-not-installed). Hope this help !

Comment: I search all around I dont know why I did not stumble upon it but I actually solved it I was thinking of what to do post it as answer or delete question

Comment: Congrats! so, post your answer and like yourself :D

Comment: @John I am facing a new problem When I run the app My activity does not appear inside emulator no app inside emulator.(ITs my first week in android development :).I dont know why

Comment: It's really hard for me to investigate your issue without detail. But, can you show me your device info? (ram, chip, year, os...). Maybe your device not support >=Lollipop emulator (me too), So, try create new AVD with API <20 (ex: 14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to 
`your_sdk_folder\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe`, double clicked and started `haxm` installation set up and installed it. After that everything started to work. It showed another version of `1.1.1` was already running in my system and I don't know why android studio showed it was already installed and still showed error showing it is not installed. I went forward with installation for new `1.1.5` version after installing the new version it started working and emulator started working.