# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.2-5309881

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to launch my app in Android Studio emulator 
I get this error:

```
    Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.2-5309881.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/jalal/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar
  - https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.2-5309881/aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Comment: please attach also the `gradle` file as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i'm new , from where i can get the gradle file ?

Comment: Hello , after fighting with this problem , it's sloved now i follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720064/hax-kernel-module-is-not-installed

Comment: check it  my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008308/5773037

Answer (score 33):

add the **google()** in **build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
     google()  -->add this line 
     jcenter()   
    }
```

Comment: Hello , And Thank you for your answer i already did and the problem is solved now

Comment: @kingjalal happy to hear that you solved your problem and you are always welcome

Answer (score 10):

I had to add the `google()` in two places to solve this

The path is `<applicationName>\build.gradle`. Note that there is another one which should not be confused with - `<applicationName>\app\build.gradle`.

1.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    ....
}
```

2.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hi, I solved this way.. in the project directory**

> android>build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

> android>app>build.gradle

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
}
```

Comment: If antivirus is installed on your system, disable it.
Windows recognizes it as an insecure file.