# I cant install intel haxm

Tags: java, android

Hi friends there is problem when i run  emultor in android studio in my lapto (aser aspire 5250) it shows me error msg "haxm is not installed" so i have cheked it and installed and now it shows as installed status but when i started emulator again it shows haxm is not instlled so i trace full path of sdk and tried to install haxm but at that time it shows me that your laptop does not support this so help me so that i can run my emulator in android studio for learning...

Comment: "*tried to install haxm but at that time it shows me that your laptop does not support this*" does it provide any specific error message?

Comment: @pshemo yes it shows Intel virtualization technology is not supported for your device..

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm) and [this](https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=3853) may helps you

Answer (score 0):

haxm uses your computer's virtualization engine to improve your emulator's performance. Try searching through your BIOS settings for some virtualization setting and make sure its enabled in there.

If there is no option or your computer doesn't have this feature, you can always disable the "Use Host GPU" option for your virtual device in its AVD settings.

Comment: How to disable it in avd.

Comment: Go to your AVD from Android Studio and click the pencile icon by the device you want to use.  There should be a checkbox under the orientation settings that says "Use Host GPU" in the "Emulated Performance" section.

Comment: I have disable it but still it shows emulation needs hardware acceleration and shows msg install haxm.

Comment: Can u tell me How to find virtualization setting in bios so that i can check first option that u have given me.

Comment: Do you see any options in your BIOS for "Virtualization Technology" or something like that? If not, your processor probably doesn't support this.  If not, then you might also try creating a whole new virtual device.  Select a system image with an armeabi-v7a ABI instead of an x86 or x86_64 system image.  And make sure "Use Host GPU" is also turned off still (this would be on the next screen)

Comment: Can u briefly explain how to create whole new virtual device?