# cannot update intel HAXM

Tags: android, intel, uninstallation, android-virtual-device, haxm

I'm trying to update haxm to version 6 but installer cannot get around uninstalling the current version. I have no idea how to solve this and I found nothing similar online. Any help ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm

Comment: different situation. As the picture shows I have the installer...it's the uninstall of previous version that has the problem

Comment: Please restart machine. Also, try to uninstall from program features

Comment: allready tried that too...it shows the same dialog. And I can't understand why it's looking in a network location :S

Answer (score 0):

1. click Start
2. type in search: regedit.exe and hit enter -> Registry editor opens
3. click Edit -> Find
4. type HAXM and hit enter.

IF SEARCH RESULT SHOWS  `LastUsedSource` in right panel

5. The result is in a folder called `SourceList` (left panel)
6. Delete the parent folder of SourceList in the left panel.
7. Install version 6.0.1 and everyting works ok.

Finally headache removed.