# HAXM is not installing in VIsual Studio 2017 pro edition

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, haxm, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install HAXM using Android SDK manager for my Xamarin app.But HAXM is showing status of **Not compatible with windows**.VT-x is already enable on my HP Elitebook 840 G1 and Hyper V is also not installed and I also tried to install it manually by HAXM installer but it is showing options only of **Repair** and **Remove**.I tried to repair but it not works.I Tried Several Links of Stackoverflow but that not works for me
Screenshots of android directory,SDK Manager,Hyper V are given below

```
[SDK Manager Screenshot][1]
[VS showing HAXM is not installed][2]
[Hyper V is not installed][3]
[Android Directory][4]
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43593229/3850012).

Comment: You failed to post your screenshots in your question. You can check the [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) to see how to show images. Forget about installing HAXM, which emulator are you using?