# Running Intel® HAXM installer takes forever with Android Studio Setup Wizard on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, react-native, intel, haxm

I have a newly installed Android Studio, upon downloading its components I've stuck on the setup wizard `Running Intel® HAXM installer`:

[image: Running Intel® HAXM installer]

What should I do? Will all my downloaded components lost if I end the task of my Android Studio with my Task Manager because just canceling Android Studio Setup Wizard might have no action AGAIN! *(I've done ending its task upon no success of cancelling it just want to customize the setup.)*

Comment: I've cancel it, the *"Cancel"* button grayed out but seems no action..

Comment: possible solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm

Comment: same issue here... (windows10)

Comment: Possibly relevant: I'm on a Mac here, and when it reached this stage it said it wanted some _security access_, and it opened a system preferences window. (I didn't know what to do there so I closed the preferences window. Then I got stuck the same as the the OP's screenshot for a few minutes, until the installer finally logged "Silent installation Pass!" and then completed.)

Comment: The behavior of the "Cancel" button shows that this is clearly a bug in the installer. I have filed a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122321146
Feel free to add any more information there that could be useful to Google (naively assuming they care).

Comment: I had the same problem on a Mac, after grating it security access it was stuck and then I force quit Android Studio. Only the next time I opened it, it booted normally... Now I'm afraid it thinks it completed but is actually only half installed!! What do I do?

Answer (score 12):

*EDIT: As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54053514/2279059, this driver is only needed for the Android virtual device. If you don't need it (it is useful for debugging, etc.), just see that other answer about how to disable the virtual device in the installer.*

This workaround did it for me on a relatively fresh Windows 10 PC:

1. Kill the installer process
2. Download the Intel HAXM driver from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm
3. From that ZIP file, run `haxm_android.exe`
4. If it complains about Hyper-V, disable Hyper-V: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All` (or see https://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/), then run it again.
5. Run the Android Studio installer again, selecting "Uninstall Previous Version".

More solutions to more potential problems may be found here: [I can't install intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm)

There is also a long checklist in another StackOverflow question for installing the Intel HAXM driver somewhere, but I could not find it again. Feel free to edit if you can find it. There are also lots of (semi-)duplicates of this question begging for cleanup and maybe assembling one answer with all the steps and things to check, not just what **I** had to do on **my** machine. If you are still stuck after reading this, keep looking around.

Answer (score 1):

Intel HAXM is required to run the app on the emulator (Android Virtual Device).
Unfortunately for me my computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology so what I did is uncheck Android Virtual Device during installation and test run all my app in my phone instead.

[image]

Comment: The setup downloads and attempts to create a HAXM installer anyway, so not checking this option is NOT a solution...   :(

Comment: It's a workaround. It works for me at the time - to setup. Maybe the new installer is different.

Comment: Oh, alright! Good for you! In my case, I don't use emulators often, so I guess it doesn't matter (for now)!  :P

Answer (score 1):

The same thing was happening with me. I just then closed the android studio and restarted the PC.

After this, I opened Android Studio and everything worked fine.