# Trouble installing HAXM in Android Studio (Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, hyper-v, haxm

Brand new to app development and am having a bit of trouble activating an Android Virtual Device (AVD) for Android Studio (Windows 10). I am trying to install HAXM but receive the attached message.

[image]

Upon going into my /installed programs/ directory to uninstall Microsoft Hyper-V, the program is not listed.  Would the Hyper-V program be listed under another name, or rather, could anyone please provide feedback as to resolving this message? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which CPU do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @magicandre1981. I have an AMD processor, and my device does not contain intel components.  I read that AMD-V is supposed to be an AMD equivalent for Intel-VT, but am not sure if Android Studio emulator devices would allow this as an alternative.

Comment: For AMD Systems you need to use HyperV Plattform https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration

Comment: Thank you for the solution @magicandre1981! Once I enabled Hyper-V, the Android Studio link to download HAXM went away.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AMD system, you can use [Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#choose-windows-hypervisor) under Windows 10 since Version 1803:

[image]

To enable [Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx) do the following steps:

- From the Windows desktop, right-click the Windows icon and select Apps and features.
- Under Related settings, click Programs and Features.
- Click Turns Windows Features on or off.
- Select Windows Hypervisor Platform

[image]

- click `ok` and reboot.

Now create a new [Android Virtual Device (AVD)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same was here too,

Ok there are 2 ways of solving this ,

First you can go to BIOS and disable the Hyper V and enable the VT x for intel. If you had not the VTx or with disabling Hyper v nothing has solved then come to Second solution.

The second is there is not a solution available for you and your computer just like me. Your cpu and computer cant install HAXM which mean you cant install and run emulator , but hang on, google has added new property to emulators to run without HAXM and you need to install those package of SDK api which has Amd virtualization or non HAXM, also even this one has not helped me, so if you were like me then you can use physical device for testing or installing linux instead of windows and use Hyper v to run emulator in android studio instead of HAXM, and i prefer Lubuntu cause of speed it will gives you if you wantes to install.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Amir Hossein.  I'll give these methods a go!

Comment: Your welcome, if they were useful to you then don't forget to check it as the best answer.

Comment: Test this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Amir, I followed a "how-to" on navigating to the BIOS, and ended up at the UEFI Firmware interface.  I saw that this is a replacement to the BIOS, but I did not see any specifications for Hyper-V upon searching the various tabs.