# Unable to install Intel HAXM on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I am trying to run AVD on Android Studio, but after I create a virtual device, and set the system image (Oreo, Nougat, Marshmallow, etc.), and then when I run it, it says that HAXM needs to be installed for better emulation performance.

[Then I press OK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc5uT.png)

[Then it asks for RAM usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clQd5.png)

[And then I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qu9t.png)

I read solutions saying that I need to install HAXM through Android Studio like this or from SDK Manager, which was more or less the same thing. But even when I install it like that, it gives this error, and I am unable to install HAXM. It doesn't let me run the AVD without it either.

-Hyper V is already unchecked
-Virtualisation is enabled, I checked it in task manager
-In SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Intel Hardware Acc...(HAXM) is unchecked/not installed, and when I check it and click on apply, the exact same process happens and it gives the same error

Also, this link they have given for installation guide, as written in the error, "To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows " This link doesn't work anymore.

I read that you can separately use the installer of HAXM by Intel to install it directly and then it should automatically work in Android Studio. There was a Github zip file linked ( https://github.com/intel/haxm ). Original Post ( [I can't install intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm) )

But I don't think it contains an installer. There are several files. Am I supposed to copy them into the "specified file" location as in the error? Which files am I supposed to put, and by what name should the folder containing it be called?

Could other solutions besides that be suggested, please?

I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, just to make sure that HAXM is installed at the start, but it still gives the same error even during first installation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The place where you'll find it][image: Github link]So I had the same problem and what I did is I straight away installed haxm manually from the GitHub link
Under the Download section click on here and then download the latest release for windows
You can find a zip file for windows and mac on the link.
You download haxm from the link extract it  and then install the setup
Worked for me...
P.S:Never tried the other methods