# android studio emulator showing blank screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, react-native

i am a noob in **react native** and was trying to ****setup android studio**** to start my react native project. after my installations i created an emulator "Pixel" but the **screen just remains blank**,

it **doesnt load** at all even when i press the power button, i have left it for up to an hour and its still doesnt load
i have tryed installing haxm manually which was the first issue i encountered, I fixed it by installing it directly.
also my emulator keeps showing offline.
i have installed android 12, 11, 10,9 & 8.1 .

i noticed from a youtube video that the device size after **wiping data** from the emulator in avd manager is **usually 1.1gb** but mine is **583mb** i dont know if this is the cause of the problem or its something else. also am **unable to install haxm** with android studio even after i activated it from my bios and "Turn Windows Feature On" setting.

Answer (score 0):

This could definitely be a result of your haxm installation not being successful, to remedy this you may want to review this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28421395/14909190)

If installing haxm doesn't resolve the issue in my experience its best to [run your emulator via command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) so you can view any errors & logs as they happen. and either look up those exact errors.

Comment: i have installed haxm manually and confirmed my the installation from cmd using `sc query intelhaxm`  and haxm is running

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem, apparently i had not  installed any, i installed my sdk from settings in sdk but i noticed that anytime i tryed creating a virtual device it still showed download so i installed from there and every thing is working fine