# Android emulator not visible in flutter devices

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-emulator, bluestacks

I have 2 android emulators, one being BlueStacks and the other, a Google Pixel 4 from Android Studio. When I create a new Flutter app and go to the Devices option, I couldn't see any of the android devices. Also, I tried to look for the devices using `flutter devices` command, but only Google and Edge appeared. Even I tried to connect BlueStacks using `adb connect` command, but didn't work. But it does run on Google and Edge. How to make my app android-compatible ?

```
C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\Users\User\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (8 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.82
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.43

• No issues found!
```

And also, can anyone explain me what is `flutter channel` and when and how to use it ?

Comment: can  you find something after running `flutter emulators` command?

Comment: Well, I got this.

```C:\Windows\system32>flutter emulators

1 available emulator:

Pixel_4_API_30 • Pixel 4 API 30 • Google • android

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager```

@YeasinSheikh, thank you and what can I do next ?

Comment: I am getting an error.
[https://pastebin.com/ALMZPJDB]

Comment: Sorry typo error, try  `flutter emulators --launch Pixel_4_API_30`

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: ```C:\Windows\System32>flutter emulator --launch Pixel_4_API_30
The Android emulator exited with code 1 during startup
Android emulator stderr:
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try
updating the emulator.
ERROR   | x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Windows:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
General information on acceleration:```

Comment: you need to install `HAXM is not installed` I think you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28418450/10157127)

Comment: When I created the emulator, Android Studio prompted me to install HAXM (I don't know what that means). I installed it and the log said HAXM installed successfully. But, now I don't know why the error comes. Will check out the link.

Comment: https://ibb.co/0rmxk1d : @YeasinSheikh, I installed HAXM

Comment: Thank you @YeasinSheikh, the link you gave worked. I just went to the Sdk location and located the HAXM setup file and installed it....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm)

Comment: Glad to help you out, I'm giving close vote while it solves your issue