# Enable hardware acceleration for AMD Phenom X4 945 for Android Studio Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-10, hardware-acceleration

I have the error "HAX kernel module is not installed", when I try to start my emulator in Android Studio. I already tried to figure out how to fix that and found out about this guide:
https://superuser.com/questions/331201/vt-x-amd-v-work-around-for-virtualbox

I entered my BIOS, and enabled the option "Secure Virtual Machine Mode", which seems to have fixed the problem for some other people. I still have the error. I also installed the installer availaible here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

Which doesn't solve the problem either. Whatelse can I try to get this going?

Comment: have you tried installing it via the SDK manager through android studio?

Comment: to clarify you:in the CPU Configuration there is a selection "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" it was disabled, once enabled and rebooted...correct?

Comment: @FredGrott that is correct

Comment: @inner_class7 I did, changed nothing either

Comment: I have a Solution by installing the armeabi-v7 sdk, which seems to work

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os

Comment: @MorrisonChang oh, seems similar, but I saw the idea with genymotion, which I used to work with some time ago and is definetely way faster. Thank you!