# Unable to run in Android Studio. Devices physical or emulated will not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have used Eclipse in the past to write and debug Android apps.  I always used the built in emulator.  I installed Android studio a few weeks ago, and have been unable to get either the emulator or my actual device to work, and am so beyond frustrated I'm about to just quit trying.  I figured I would ask before I did that though.

So with the emulator, when I try to debug, I get the error message, "Cannot launch AVD in emulator." ... "ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!  Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!"

I've read about this, but I believe since I don't have an Intel processor, the solutions I've seen don't apply.  I have an AMD Athlon II X2.  I'm running on 64-bit Windows 7.

The solutions I've seen are to do as the error message says and install HAXM.  But, what can I do to get past this since I don't have an intel processor.

My other issue is that my device is not showing up.  I've done the click and unclick the allow usb debugging.  Made no difference.  I've tried 2 devices.  Nothing.

Anyone have ANY IDEA what I need to do?  I don't think I've ever been so frustrated.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)?

Comment: AMD has an equivalent instruction set (AMDV), but its only supported on Linux.  You cannot use the built in emulator on AMD on Windows.  I'd suggest Gennymotion instead.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. While you attach your device to your USB, see if it requires drivers.
2. You can see your device in Device Manager. If you find your device something as shown below:

[image]

, then it means you manually need to install ADB drivers and once your drivers are installed, you will be able to use your device for debugging.

This blog explains very well on how to [Manually installing Android ADB USB Driver](http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/).