# Why is HAXM refusing to run on my ryzen 2600x system?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization

[System info](https://pastebin.com/2CGs2agY):

```
 AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
 PRIME X470-PRO Mobo
 8gb ddr4 kingston hyperx
 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 4GB
 Windows 10 pro Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
```

I would have preferred to add this as a comment to answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration) post, but I don't have 50 reputation.

I am stuck on step 2 of [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31458503/9438459)

I've tried disabling Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform, all virtualization options are enabled through BIOS, but HAXM refuses to install.

[image: Error message]

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805316/9438459) indicates the exact opposite, and that does not work either.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263563/9438459) says AMD only works on Linux. But the linked [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#accel-vm) they point to does not mention this restriction. So it's possibly been patched.

EDIT:
just going to add random extra pieces of information that I find about my system to help answer questions that may come up.

[Virtualization enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4LwC.png)

[My Windows features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFKWy.png) (and also [with windows hypervisor platform enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chl9X.png), still returns error after reboot)

I ran the following command before going into my windows features options, it appeared to do nothing however as Hyper-v was still showing as enabled in the GUI:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Comment: I don't see 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' enabled. See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: I've enabled and disabled it the same way I have with hyper-v and it hasn't changed the error message, but I'll try again real quick. EDIT: it's [enabled](https://i.imgur.com/S7uFmui.png) now, still no luck after reboot.

Comment: If you've followed the instructions in the Google blog post, and still not working (after reboots) edit your post to list out the details of your system, CPU model, RAM, Windows version, etc. in case others encounter your problem. Do check existing [Android bug reports with AMD keyword](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190923%2B%20AMD) for similar issues/workarounds.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at making a report there as well. Unfortunately I'm quite sure I meet the requirements listed in the blog, perusing the android docs for anything extra, but it doesn't look like there are any missing steps.