# Failed to install Intel HAXM android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I cant install haxm in android studio
cpu : AMD Phenom || x6 1100t

Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: `C:\Users\AFRADA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log1894.txt`
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at `C:\Users\AFRADA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log1894.txt`
Installer log contents:

```
=== Logging started: 12/22/2019  10:32:57 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely don't need Intel HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Mode) in AMD processors, because they are AMD processors.

Just enable (check) Windows Hypervisor Platform in Windows features as shown below.
[image]

Now, you can start emulators. No need of Intel HAXM.

Here is official link: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable hyper-v in control panel then select window future if hyper-v is disable 
Active Virtualization Technology (VT-x)  at bios setting

Comment: hyper-v is disable and enable SVM mode in bios

Comment: HAXM says Hyper-V is enabled when Windows says it is not

Comment: Sory im found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os  he say AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

Comment: dont help this comment :(

Comment: im so sory about this..but im found this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps from this article, you need to enable virtualization from your BIOS settings in order to run your android emulators.

i do this on every machine 1st time i install android studio/HAX, hope it works for you

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ITOps-Talk-Blog/Step-By-Step-Enabling-Hyper-V-for-use-on-Windows-10/ba-p/267945

Comment: my SVM mode enable in bios

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for TekTutorialsHub for the idea - in my computer (Win10, Android Studio 3.6.1) the problem was connected with antivirus program protection of memory integrity (Windows Defender Security Center - Device security/Core isolation details/Memory integrity/off). Restart the computer.
In older version on the same hardware everything worked perfect, the problem began after Android Studio /SDK update.

Comment: This gives the impression of mostly saying "Thanks." and "Me too." If you intend this to actually answer the question at the top of this page, then please [edit] and rephrase to make the answering part more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to solve just go to your BIOS and enable the Virtualization Technology (VT-x),You can disable the Hyper-V from the windows feature and check if it works. Thanks