# Can't Install HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I am new to Android and when I install HAXM for android studio, the following error occurred.

[image]

I have tried some solutions for this error, like 'Unchecking the Hyper-V in **Turn Windows features on or off** and enabling the Virtualization Technology from BIOS', but it didn't work. Is there another way to solve this problem? Thanks.

In case my computer's specification is needed, [image]

Comment: HAXM will work without any issues on an intel processor, but on AMD it has some issues see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os, I had similar issues in the past and ended up using an intel processor. If it does not work out for you I think the best way would be to use a real device instead of emulator.

Comment: Thanks bud. Genymotion helped me solve this. xD