# unable to install haxm on andriod studio by using amd processor

Tags: android-studio

im using tuf gaming fx505dd with amd ryzen 5 processor, and window 10 home edition. 
Now i cant install intel haxm on android studio, and unable to find hyper-v on my laptop .
How can i fix the problems ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel's HAXM equivalent for AMD on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)

Comment: There are many questions and answers about AMD and HAXM, but I use Intel, so I'm not up-to-date on which is the latest correct solution. I'd look at any of the more recents answers and comments.