# Unable to run Intel HAXM installer: Cannot start process, the working directory does not exist

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, hyper-v, haxm

How to resolve this error which I am getting while installing HAXM installer.

Unable to run Intel HAXM installer: Cannot start process, the working directory
'C:\Users\surabhi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelarated_Execution_Manager does not exist.

I also tried to download HAXM installer directly from Intel's website but couldn't succeed and I have also tried enabling and disabling Hyper-V.

Answer (score 33):

It's because the downloaded installer might be missing. So download it again.

Instead of trying to install inside AVD Manager install from SDK Manager.

Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Check Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM Installer) and Click Apply, it will start download and install.

Comment: Worked for me Android studio (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)

Answer (score 10):

My tiny contribution:
I had the same problem, I then tried to install from the SDK tools, it said it was installed and when I tried to run the emulator it said that HAXM was missing. At least from the SDK tools, the folder was created.
Tried to install it many times with no success. Then I went to the folder indicated (...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelarated_Execution_Manager) and ran the installer manually and it worked.

In case this may help anyone

Answer (score 1):

Tools>SDK Manager>Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK:

Go to SDK Tools tab>check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)">Apply

Answer (score 1):

When you try to run the emulator from the AVD manager, you'll probably notice that there is an alert to install the intel HAXM, try to install it by just clicking install, if you are able to run the emulator, congratulation! you did solve problem.

If not you may have to install it manually by going into the following path:

```sh
C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

Just replace `$user` with your.
You'll find the installation file so run it.

Congratulation!

Answer (score 0):

If your system uses AMD processor, then Intels HAXM doesn't work. Refer [Intel's HAXM equivalent for AMD on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD processor you should use WHPX. It worked for me.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx)

Steps in case the link is not working in the future:

> Before you can enable WHPX, your computer must meet the following
>   requirements:
>
> - Intel processors: Support for Virtualization Technology (VT-x),
>     Extended Page Tables (EPT), and Unrestricted Guest (UG) features. VT-x
>     must be enabled in your computer's BIOS settings.
> - AMD processors: AMD Ryzen processor recommended. Virtualization or SVM must be enabled
>     in your computer's BIOS settings.
> - Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 or higher (download from developer.android.com)
> - Android Emulator version 27.3.8 or higher (download using the SDK Manager)
> - Windows 10 with April 2018 Update or higher
>
> To install WHPX on Windows, follow these steps:
>
> 1. From the Windows desktop, right-click the Windows icon and select
>      Apps and features.
> 2. Under Related settings, click Programs and Features.
> 3. Click Turns Windows Features on or off.
> 4. Select Windows Hypervisor Platform
> 5. Click OK.
> 6. Once the installation has finished, restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions below worked for me, just enabled the **virtualization setting** in BIOS.
The original issue comment: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors/issues/17#issuecomment-646343114

> 1- Restart your computer
> 2 - On the boot up image, quickly press f12 to enter bios (might be a different function key depending on your motherboard)
> 3 - Go to BIOS configurations (navigation is done with arrow keys enter key to go into or select, and esc to go back)
> 4 - Go to the M.T.I. tab (should be the default tab)
> 5 - Go into "Advanced Frequency Settings"
> 6 - Scroll to "SVM Mode"
> 7 - You can also look for anything that says virtualization or VT-x if you dont see SVM
> 8 - Click, enter
> 9 - Highlight "enable" and click enter
> 10 - Click ESC to go back
> 11 - Scroll to the right to get to the save tab
> 12 - Highlight "Save and quit"
> 13 - Click enter
> 14 - Your computer will restart. Try to reinstall the SDK Tool, "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor (installer) through android studio

Answer (score 0):

I booted into my BIOS and enabled Hyper-virtualization. And that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

My tiny contribution: I had the same problem, I then tried to install from the SDK tools, it said it was installed and when I tried to run the emulator it said that HAXM was missing. At least from the SDK tools, the folder was created. Tried to install it many times with no success. Then I went to the folder indicated (...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelarated_Execution_Manager) and ran the installer manually and it worked.

In case this may help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution
I am using hp

1. Goto bios settings of your laptop or pc.
2. Goto system configuration
3. Find Vertualization Technology
4. Enable it

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all possible solutions... after a long day... this was my solution...

SO Windows + Intel processor

Error: User file name has a blank space in the middle, so I changed file name, this was my mistake during installation of the SO, so the emulator never worked

1. Open the Android studio log file to check the error
2. Uninstall HAXM (Control panel => programs => unistall)
3. Uninstall Android Studio
4. Reinstall Android Studio
5. Restart computer

finally it worked