# unable to create virtual device in android studio , ERROR : HAXM installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtualdisplay

At the time of creating virtual device , it says haxm is not installed.

In my laptop I have AMD Ryzen 5 , and haxm is an intel's tool and even I don't find the option of Hyper - V in my System.
the error says :

```
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log2.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 7/18/2020  12:46:05 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

=== Logging stopped: 7/18/2020  12:46:08 ===
Done
```

Comment: visit this links maybe helo you...
[`enter link description here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable VT-X virtual technology from BIOS, if you are using Windows then go to BIOS , and you will find VT-x technology just enable it. after that you need to install the HAXM that will provide you better acceleration in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify your motherboard and CPU virtualization support it's enabled.

When you turn your PC/Laptop on, enter to BIOS setup (usually pressing F2 or DEL Key), and verify the next options are anabled:

```
Intel VT-x:
BIOS Setup -> Advanced -> CPU Configuration -> Intel Virtualization Technology -> Enabled.
```

```
AMD SVM Mode:
BIOS Setup -> Advanced -> CPU Configuration -> SVM Mode -> Enabled.
```

```
IOMMU
BIOS Setup -> Advanced -> North Bridge Configuration-> IOMMU -> Enabled.
```

Then, start up your PC/Laptop commonly, boot up on your Operating system (Windows, Linux, etc), and then install Intel HAXM. If everything was OK, it should install without troubles.